# Rails Paperclip, Jbuilder returning incorrect URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jbuilder

I have a working install of Paperclip on Rails.

I can obtain the correct URL from the console:

```
listing.cover_photo.url(:medium) -> https://....amazonaws.com/listings/cover_photos/000/000/133/medium/travel?1521715173
```

But when I try return it from my Jbuilder template in "/api/v1/listings/index.json.jbuilder", it seems to add "api/v1/listings_controller", and I get the following:

```
https://....amazonaws.com/api/v1/listings_controller/listings/cover_photos/000/000/133/medium/travel?1521715173
```

I tried wrapping it in a method on the model, but no luck.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the index action of your controller and the jbuilder views it renders?

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the reply. It was my bad. I was simultaneously trying to override the as_json method in the index controller, which wasn't needed anymore since using Jbuilder. I couldn't see how it could affect the Paperclip URL, but after removing the as_json method, eveything works perfectly.